# Change value of multidimensional array in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, multidimensional-array

I am having the strangest problem and looking for help. I have an array of arrays of integers. I am trying to change these values and I cannot find out how. Here is what I tried:

```
[[multidim-array objectAtIndex:0] replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
```

what this does is get the first array from the main array and change the integer at the first index to one. Or at least, that's what I think it should be doing. and its what the other threads here said it should do. But I am getting strange behavior.

The above code, for some reason, changes the first value of EVERY array to 1. It's as if I run the code 10 times on every array in the multidim-array array.

Anyone know why this could be happening? If my phrasing was unclear, what I am trying to do is the objective-c equivelant of `multidim-array[0][0] = 1;`

EDIT: Someone told me this should work so here is info about how I am handling the array. The array starts out filled with 0s. There is a lot of code affecting the array but it shouldn't matter because I have breakpoints trailing through so I can see what each line of code does to the array. Before I run that line, the numbers are all 0s. I try and change one value, and they a whole bunch of them become changed. I am still looking into it if no one knows what's happening :/

Comment: This should work. Can you post any other code that deals with these arrays to see if the problem is there? On a side note, I recommend using the new notation for number and container literals. In your case, the above code would become: `[multidim-array[0] replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@(1)];`

Comment: trying what you said, will update this comment in a bit... ok I put in `[multidim-array[0] replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@(1)];` and it did the same thing... :/ I am about to update my question with more info about how I handle the array

Comment: Uhoh. I found the issue and I still can't fix it. I clearly was unaware of how arrays work :/ each array within the multidim-array is a pointer to the same array. when I edit one I edit them all, nothing I can do about it. Not sure how to proceed?

Comment: please post the code where you initialize the array

Comment: I will in a second, but I have an idea that might fix everything... stay tuned.

Comment: @IAmTheAg: `multidim-array` isn't a valid identifier. You should paste actual code.

Comment: The problem ended up having to do with how I defined the array. I didn't realize that the pointers would affect the array how they did. cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you've assigned the same inner array to every element of the outer array.

BTW, you can actually write this:

```
multidim_array[0][0] = @1;
```

Comment: After a long time of looking at code, I came to that conclusion. It completely slipped my mind how pointers worked. I was unaware that it worked like that :/ In any case, thanks for the answer, and also that tip will come in handy.